# How do I check if a VB6 application is running (and not hung on a system error) from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, vb6

I need to monitor a legacy application written in vb6 from a C# service and force-quit/relaunch it whenever it hangs.

How do I check if a VB6 application is running (and not either hung on a system error or crashed completely) from C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) type to monitor for crashes.

However, it's tough to tell if an app is 'temporarily busy' or actually 'hung', so we will need to make a few assumptions.

- Lets say that this is a windows forms app (in VB6) that has an active message pump.
- Lets also say that a timeout of 10 seconds is a good indication of a 'hung' app.

Any function that relies on that message pump to complete will be a good indicator of a hung app, given that it exceeds the timeout.

You can use any of the `SendMessage` commands to basically 'join' with the other app's message pump.

Something like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
...

NativeMethods.SendMessage(hWnd, NativeMethods.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
```